# Get exposure time in OpenNI

Tags: kinect, openni

I capture RGBD video using Kinect with auto exposure mode turned on. I'm using OpenNI/OpenNI2. Because of auto exposure, the exposure time for each frame could vary. In OpenNI or OpenNI2, is there a way to read out the exposure time for each frame?

Answer (score 1):

In OpenNi2, you can use the [`VideoStream::getCameraSettings()`](https://github.com/occipital/OpenNI2/blob/master/Include/OpenNI.h#L893) of your RGB stream. And then use [`CameraSettings::getExposure()`](https://github.com/occipital/OpenNI2/blob/master/Include/OpenNI.h#L1886).

```
int exposure = -1;
openni::CameraSettings* pCamSettings = pStreamImage->getCameraSettings();
if (pCamSettings)
{
    exposure = pCamSettings->getExposure();
}
```